# Is a bijective mapping from a compact set to a $T_1$ space is a homeomorphism?

Tags: general-topology

It is proved that the a bijective mapping from a compact set to a hausdorff space is a homeomorphism. Is the result true if hausdorffness is replaced by $T_1$ property?

Comment: Do you want to assume anything about the map aside from bijective-ness? Perhaps continuity, in at least one direction? If not: consider any map from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$ that basically permutes the points randomly.

Comment: @JohnHughes "map" often refers to continuous functions in topology.

Comment: @Arthur: I'm aware of that. Then again, it's also often used *without* that intent, and I wanted to know what OP intended.

Answer (score 2):

No, take any infinite compact Hausdorff space $X$ (e.g. $X=[0,1]$) and
$$X\to X$$
$$x\mapsto x$$
with the cofinite topology on the right side. It is clearly a continuous bijection. But it is not a homeomorphism because the right side is not Hausdorff. Indeed, the cofinite topology is Hausdorff only on finite spaces.